# Angular 2 remove multiple objects from an array

Tags: angular

I have an array with multiple objects. My app has an option to "filter" the objects and return the filtered array.

This is how I do that:

```
this.result.combos.forEach((combo) => {
                  console.log("Analyzing combo:");
                  console.log(combo);
          if (combo.atk < minStat || combo.atk > maxStat)
          {
                this.result.combos.splice(this.result.combos.indexOf(combo), 1); 
                console.log("COMBO HAS BEEN REMOVED");
          }
            else
                console.log("COMBO HAS BENE STAYED");
       });
```

My problem is, that I need to run this method MULTIPLE times in order to reach the result. Each time I run this method, my objects are filtered partially.

**For example**: I have 200 objects, and I filter the minStat/maxStat value of them to show me only those records with minStat/maxStat value of 50/100.
The code will remove about 70 records from the array, but will remain alot of results without an minStat/maxStat of 50-100.

I've been digging into this and I guess it's releated to the `splice` method. but I found no alternative to this issue.

Any help?

Comment: Use array.filter method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is filter the array based on some predicate. You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter%20filter) function:

```
let newArray = this.result.combos.filter(combo => combo.atk < minStat || combo.atk > maxStat);
```

`newArray` will be filled with all elements that match `combo.atk < minStat || combo.atk > maxStat` and `this.result` will still contain all original elements.